# nginx configuration issue, ports already in use

Tags: php, mysql, macos, curl, nginx

I recently migrated to Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10 and I followed [this tutorial](http://blog.frd.mn/install-nginx-php-fpm-mysql-and-phpmyadmin-on-os-x-mavericks-using-homebrew/).

To set up my machine, After a lots of hiccups I finally managed to reach a point where I find just a single issue happening due to nginx port issues.

If I do

`sudo nginx`

I get this

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:306 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:306 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:306 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:306 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:306 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

which means 443 and 306 ports are being used somewhere else

and when I do

```
sudo lsof -i:443
```

I get this

```
COMMAND PID USER FD TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx 548 root 13u IPv4 0xce9cf564560ec22b 0t0 TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx 549 nobody 13u IPv4 0xce9cf564560ec22b 0t0 TCP *:https (LISTEN)
```

similarly for `sudo lsof -i:306`

I get

```
COMMAND PID USER FD TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx 548 root 14u IPv4 0xce9cf564560ed3cb 0t0 TCP *:306 (LISTEN)
nginx 549 nobody 14u IPv4 0xce9cf564560ed3cb 0t0 TCP *:306 (LISTEN)
```

Now if nginx is already using these ports, how come it is claiming that Address is already in use

and when I run my app in browser say abc.dev.com

I get no response from server, after sometime browser simply tells me

The connection has timed out
    The server at abc.dev.com is taking too long to respond.

If i do `curl http://abc.dev.com` I get

**curl: (7) Failed to connect to abc.dev.com port 80: Operation timed out**

Also If I do

```
nginx.start
```

I get this:

**/Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist: Operation already in progress**

if I do::

`nginx.stop`  //it works, I think it stops

if I do:

```
nginx.restart
```

I get this:

**/Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist: Could not find specified service**

I have ran out of ideas and can't think of anything that could be causing this. Any Ideas are highly appreciated...

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Author of the guide you've linked above here. It seems like you managed to get Nginx running without the proper LaunchDaemon.

Can you make sure, when you enter "`nginx.stop`", the process is really stopped? (`ps aux`).

Regarding the last error while "`nginx.restart`": thats normal, because you already stopped the service before with "`nginx.stop`". So a restart (actually: stop && start) will come up with the error since it's trying to stop an already stopped service.

Anyway, since your issue is pretty much guide-dependent / relevant, I'm not sure if StackOverflow is the right place for this discussion. Let's better continue in the comment section of the guide.

Comment: I can't see my comment. If you can approve my comment I will follow up.

Comment: @Mike It's already approved. Here's a [direct link](http://blog.frd.mn/install-nginx-php-fpm-mysql-and-phpmyadmin-on-os-x-mavericks-using-homebrew/#comment-1935703130).

Comment: Thanks Buddy, I must say great tutorial but that said I replied to your comment